# Roll up data for join in spark without using spark-sql

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, left-join, right-join

How to roll up data of one file based on one variable before joining it to other file in spark ? I need to join the two files so that there should not be any repeated key of that column .
Example : Data of one file

```
name,country,marks,score
a,India,12,11
b,Australia,10,9
a,England,12,10
a,America,11,18
b,India,16,12
c,America,17,22
```

Data of second file

```
name2,City,ID
a,Delhi,we1
b,Bangalore,we2
a,Gurgaon,we1
a,Mumbai,we3
c,Delhi,we4
```

After rolling first file, it should be like

```
name,country,marks,score
a,India England America,12 12 11, 11 10 18
b,Australia India,10 16, 9 12 
c,America,17,22
```

After rolling second file, it should be like

```
a, Delhi Gurgaon Mumbai,we1 we1 we3
b,Bangalore, we2
c,Delhi ,we4
```

and after rolling these files, I want to do left join, right join and other types join in Spark.

Comment: i was trying to use groupBy by "name" variable . but output is RDD[String, Iterable[String]]

Comment: val line = sc.textFile("file1.csv")
line: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] =MapPartitionsRDD
val withoutheader = dropheader(data1)
withoutheader: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] =MapPartitionsRDD 
val group = withouheader.groupBy(l=>{
val parts= l.split(',')
(parts(0))})
group: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[String])] = ShuffledRDD[16] at groupBy 
output after group.collect is :  Array[(String, Iterable[String])] = Array((b,CompactBuffer(b,Australia,10,9, b,India,16,12)), (a,CompactBuffer(a,India,12,11, a,England,12,10, a,America,11,18)), (c,CompactBuffer(c,America,17,22)))

Comment: but the expected output after rolling up should be  
 Array[(String,[String])] = Array((b,(b,Australia India ,10 16, 9 12 )), (a,(a,India England America ,12 12 11 ,11 10 18)), (c,(c,America,17,22))